# What is the probability of getting exactly one two and one three in a 5 card draw?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a 52 cards deck, what is the probability of getting exactly one 2 and one 3 if 5 cards are drawn. I'm wondering what is the difference between doing it the following two ways. Intuitively I would like to do it this way:

There are ${4\choose1}$ ways of choosing a 3 and ${4\choose1}$ of choosing a 2. For the other 3 cards there are 44 cards left so that leaves ${44\choose3}$

So...

$\dfrac{{4\choose1}.{4\choose1}.{44\choose3}}{{52\choose5}}$

Is doing it this way correct or not. It looks similar to the hypergeometric distribution but since it has to do with three distinct groups can you do it like that?

The alternative way I'd like to do this problem but end up with a different solutions is:

$=\frac{4}{52}.\frac{4}{51}.\frac{44}{50}.\frac{43}{49}
.\frac{42}{48}.\frac{5!}{1!.1!.3!}$

4 out of 52 cards are 2's, 4 out of 51 are 3's then the other three cards are chosen as  44/50, 43/49, 42/48. Then it can be arranged in a word permutation of 
$\frac{5!}{1!.1!.3!}$.

Is the first way considered like the hypergeometric distribution or no because it contains two succeses and one failure?

Thank you for anyone who can help.

Comment: Don't these give the same value?

Comment: @lulu They do give the same value.

Comment: Is the first way I did it consistent with the hypergeometric distribution or no because it contains three distinct groups? Also okay I just re-entered all of the above and I'm glad that the two answers are the same.

Comment: You can think of your first calculation as using a special case of the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both your calculations and get $\frac{1892}{23205}$ for both of them.

Comment: Can I ask if the first way of doing it is a hypergeometric distribution or no because it contains three distinct groups? Okay thank you I just re-entered everything and got the same. Pheww!

Comment: As I read [WIkipedia on the hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) it would apply more to getting two out of (twos and threes) and three of the rest.  The article says you have to classify the choices into two exclusive sets.  This calculation is certainly along the lines of the hypergeometric distribution.